# Secret area (???) Overflow #4

Tags: the-end-is-nigh

In the upper center of the Overflow #4 we can find a secret area (???). 
When you head left you find this area:
[image]
I tried jumping the best I could but I cannot reach the other side. 
What I am supposed to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to hang yourself to the cliff and then jump with a long jump to the left side. The rest you have to do is some climbing to the top, then jump back to the right side with another cliffhanger-jump. It is a tough section with some really close jumps.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that hanging allowed farther jumps! Thanks